# Automatic Docker stop after running in CentOS

Tags: linux, docker, cron, centos, centos7

I'm working in a `CentOS 7` that I use to execute `Docker Containers` using a web.

Well, what I have is a web where the user can click a button and a `Docker container` is executed. That part is functional.

Now I need to implement a system function that executes a console command to kill the `Docker container` after 5min that this is executed.

For example:

The user clicks the option to run a container, and a new container is executed with the id `7c14e894ab00`. What I want is that 5min later the console will execute automatically `docker stop 7c14e894ab00`, and the container will be stopped.

I've been looking for information and I found some ideas such as `Crontab` or something like that, but the `Linux` systems are not my stuff.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

you can make your own script that starts the container and stop it after 5 minutes. It will be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

RESULT=$(sudo docker run -d MYCONTAINER)
sleep 5m
echo $RESULT
sudo docker stop $RESULT
```

So you can execute this script instead the command you are running to start the container.

Comment: I want to implement that without sleep, because I need to run other things in the system.

Comment: The best way is to run the script at the background, and if you are running under a normal linux systems, other task could be done in the meantime. If your script is named as myScript.sh, you could do `sudo bash myScript.sh &` or if you made the scrpt executable, you can type `sudo ./myScript.sh`

Answer (score 0):

> console command to kill the Docker container after 5min that this is
>   executed.

As the containers which are stopped/exited over a period of time increases and will pile up the memory in the server. **If the containers are not required once it is stopped you can use** **[docker --rm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up-rm)** **which will remove the container as soon as it is stopped.**

If the containers are required even after they are stopped you can ignore `--rm` option. **To delete all the stopped containers later use** **[docker container prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_prune/)**.

> Stop the container after a period of time

You need to write your own script to call the docker stop command to stop the containers running.